# How to create an app in Bigcommerce and Install it in the Bigcommerce Store

Tags: php, bigcommerce

I have created an app using my store details in Bigcommerce . I am facing problems understanding the Bigcommerce concept and flow .  My Goal is to make a free flowing Single Click Install app in the Bigcommerce code . Kindly help me with the necessary code and concepts.

Thanks

Comment: to understand the flow refer to the documentation given in the website

Comment: i have passed the authurl and load url into the technical details of the app ... when i click on install it just goes on installing ... but nothing is shown after that